# How can I use dependency injection in a unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, new-operator

I'm trying to unit test a function accessed via a dependency injection and I can't figure out how to make it run when it is put through test explorer.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using RDM_API.Models;

namespace RDM_API.UnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class AddSession_Test
    {
        private IRDM_Functions test;

        public AddSession_Test(IRDM_Functions Test)
        {
            this.test = Test;
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void addSession_Test_True()
        {
            //Arange
            string sessionId = "apples";
            string user = "Brendan";
            string sessionName = "Test";
            bool expected = true;

            //Act
            bool actual = test.AddSessionAndUserId(sessionId, user, sessionName);

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
```

In this case have called it `test` and the Visual Studio Error checker shows no issues, what I believe is happening is that because the injection is not tagged with a `[Test]`. Any corrections to this would be appreciated. I have tried to go back to using `new` but this results in the error `Error  CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'configuration' of 'RDM_Functions.RDM_Functions(IConfiguration)` and any `test.` functions error as `Error CS0103  The name 'test' does not exist in the current contex`.I have been told that I should mock `Iconfiguration` but I am unsure how to do so any help with this would be great.

Comment: How is it that some code can only be accessed by dependency injection? Not being able to access it elsewhere doesn't make a whole lot of sense since if you couldn't access it elsewhere, your dependency injection container wouldn't be able to access it either.

Comment: Since I have added the dependency injection to the code I have not been able to use the `new` statement without the error ```Error  CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'configuration' of 'Class.Class(Iconfiguration)```

Comment: Well, of course. You need to pass it an `IConfiguration` to new it. You should mock `IConfiguration`.

Comment: I'm currently unsure how to do that, I have edited the question, but in the meantime I will try and work out how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure how/why it works, but by using the following code

```
namespace RDM_API.UnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class sessionExists_Test
    {
        private readonly IRDM_Functions rdm;

        [TestMethod]
        public void sessionExists_Test_True()
        {
            //Arange
            Models.RDM_Functions test = new Models.RDM_Functions((Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration)rdm);
            string sessionId = "banana";
            string user = "glenn";
            string sessionName = "kong";
            bool expected = true;
            test.deleteSession(sessionId, user);
            test.AddSessionAndUserId(sessionId, user, sessionName);

            //Act
            bool actual = test.sessionExists(sessionId);

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
            test.deleteSession(sessionId, user);
        }
        
    }
}
```

The configuration is put into the class in the usual position `private readonly IRDM_Functions rdm;` and then using a `new` to reference it `Models.RDM_Functions test = new Models.RDM_Functions((Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration)e);`, the test explorer is able to use the functions.

Comment: It might be better for you to use something like [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/moq/) for **mocking** `IConfiguration`, since this code will fail the moment you try and use the injected object.

Comment: I don't currently understand how to use Moq, so I'll work on it, however could you explain why the code won't work?

Comment: It won't work because `rdm` is `null`. So anything that depends on the injected object will throw a `NullReferenceException`. You are able to cast `rdm` to `IConfiguration` only because `rdm` is `null` (see [this example](https://rextester.com/SMGRQ18559)). If `rdm` actually had a value, you would get an `InvalidCastException` ( see [this example](https://rextester.com/CJVHIG64625)).